# Troubles when using Pause in the game from "New Game"

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

Pause works great in the Main and "Are you sure want to quit?" scene
But if i press "YES, i want to quit" - i go to main menu and if i start New Game
there are always problems with graphics and if i press Pause in this New game - the scene "Are you sure want to quit?" freezes forever every time!

This is problem and screenshots of logic from Main "Scenebasic" and "Are you sure want to quit?" Scene

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: What tutorial are you following? That is too little info to speculate.

Comment: I combine several tutorials. there is no exact tutorial concerning my situation. I just want to have main menu (that i already have and it works also well) and ability to press e.g. P while being in a game so that the screen with "Are you sure want to quit?" should appear. As i mentioned, if i press No, logically, you just resume the game. But it works only inside 1 particular game that is being played. but if i press No, you go to main Menu logically (and there you may quit the game). and if you want  New game after  "Are you sure want to quit?" ->"Yes" sequence the whole game works incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by adding Remove scene - Main scene every time before setting new Main scene when clicking New Game. 
It can be seen on the screenshot that Main scenes double!
Yay for me